# commercial support for hbase/hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I know cloudera is on the forefront of providing commercial support for hadoop/hbase/hdfs. 
Are there any other vendors who provide this?

-Chinmay

Answer (score 4):

[Cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/) provides commercial support for both hadoop and hbase. There are other vendors such as Karmasphere which provide tools. No one else provides support for hadoop on the scale of Cloudera.

UPDATE: [Hortonworks](http://hortonworks.com/), a hadoop spinoff from Yahoo is also entering this space.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Sematext](http://www.sematext.com/) provides support about HBase, Hadoop/MapReduce/HDFS.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, only [Cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/) can provide reliable *24x7 technical support* for Hadoop and HBase.

[Tokenizer](http://www.tokenizer.ca/support) provides commercial *development* subscription services (Nutch, Hadoop, HBase, Lucene, SOLR), including code reviews and critical assessments of your design and architecture, custom builds, bug fixes, technical monitoring and performance tuning, and etc.

There are some new really big players too, such as Platform Computing.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from above mentioned vendors you also have :

[Talend](http://talend.com/)

[WANdisco](http://www.wandisco.com/)

[EMC Greenplum](http://www.greenplum.com/)

[DataStax](http://www.datastax.com/)

[Intel](http://www.intel.com)